# Log into Peoplesoft Using Web Service

Tags: web-services, authentication, peoplesoft

I am trying to build a third party application which needs to be in sync with the PeopleSoft application. Is there any CI through which I can authenticate users into PeopleSoft database using web services? The authentication has to be from the third party custom application and not using the single signon option that peoplesoft provides where we log onto the portal first and redirect to the other application. If any other successful implementation has been done please do share.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know PeopleSoft doesn’t provide anyway to externally generate the PSTOKEN token credential which is required when accessing secured PeopleSoft pages. I’m guessing that’s what you’re trying to achieve.
You could implement it the other way around, meaning have the third party system leave some cookie in the browser that would allow the user to authenticate against PeopleSoft with some custom Signon PeopleCode which would read that cookie.
Or (and most recommended) have both systems (PeopleSoft and the 3rd party) rely on an external SSO solution such as Active Directory/Kerberos. That’s the way I’ve tackled this issue many times before.